# Как, с помощью какой библиотеки можно реализовать нейросеть для симулятора нейроэволюции?

Tags: java, нейронные-сети

Нужна нейросеть для симуляции на Java. Начал делать симулятор эволюции клеток только вместо генетического алгоритма использовать нейросеть. Клетка может "видеть" что находится справа, слева, сверху и снизу ,по таким же направлениям может передвигаться, поедать другие клетки, делится и еще некоторые вещи,  имеет запас энергии если ее нет, умирает, если ее слишком много тоже умирает. Как, с помощью какой библиотеки можно реализовать нейросеть для клеток? Клетки должны обучатся независимо друг от друга, при делении дочерней клетке передается копия нейросети клетки родителя.
[image: Как-то так это выглядит сейчас, клетки действуют случайно]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Нейросеть в таком случае есть должна опиаться на некую "оценку позиции" то есть состояния, изветсного клетке, но для обучения должна быть и некая объективная информация о плохой ситуации. Мертвая клетка уже ничего не может передеть, поэтому если клетка близка к смерти, она может засчет этого как бы подтвердить, что предыдущие состояния были нехороши, за счет этого можно построить обучение, и если всё же выживет, то передать информацию потомкам.